# Is it a good idea to put a WebView into each item of a ListView on Android?

Tags: android, listview, webview

Is it a good idea to put a `WebView` into each item of a `ListView` on Android?
Or should I just use the `TextView` with `Spannd`?

I tried the `Html.fromHtml()` with `ImageGetter` to get the `Spanned`, but it does lots of parsing works for you and hard to customize it. And also it's different from what you see on a `WebView`.

Any idea would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a terrible idea in terms of performance (not that I've tried it). Maybe you could explain further why you need to render HTML in each row, and we can see if there's an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, and I'm just curious about other implemetation if it's better. The Spanned with ImageGetter does not handle the auto-scaling and have to do the TextView.setText() every time when the image is downloaded and ready to show on screen.

Comment: And of course I have to implement the async download task myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WebViews in ListView elements, if you absolutely need to. Afaik, the only problem with this solution is, that it takes a relatively long time for ListView to measure the height of the list elements which have WebViews. But if you tested it, and it worked alright, then it's good to go I think.

Comment: Thanks, and I tried the WebViews on my ListView. It is obviously slow on creating the ListView and seems ok after the reusable convertViews start doing their jobs.

Comment: But I think I won't put them in my ListView due to the performance issue.

Comment: @shiami What alternative did you try instead of using webviews as listview items